# Memory-friendly way to draw a circle in SDL or any language?

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, sdl, sdl-2

The answer doesn't have to be sdl specific.

Here's the current one I wrote but I think it will consume lot of memory too as I will add movements to circle too.

I am using `f(p)= xsquare + ysquare - rsquare` 
to render the pixels inside circle (mid point theoram I guess) .

Please make it simple as I am a beginner. 
and also is it ok to make many header files for your program ? is it good practice?

```
void add( SDL_Window *window ,SDL_Renderer *renderer,int r )
{
    int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int x,y,k;
for(i=1 ; i<= r; ++i)
    {
        for(j=1 ; j<= r; ++j)
        {
            k=(i*i)+(j*j)-(r*r);
            if(k <= 0)
            {
                x=20;
                y=400;
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer ,i+r-1+x,j+r-1+y);
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer ,-i+r+1+x,-j+r+1+y);
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer ,-i+r+1+x,j+r-1+y);
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer ,i+r-1+x,-j+r+1+y);
            }
        }
    }
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: "... or in any language".  There are many languages that have graphics primitives.  Java comes with a GUI framework.

Comment: Why do you think it will consume a lot of memory?

Comment: @molbdnilo  because I have to  add loop and  every pixel goes through a code where it checks circle equation algorithm . If I make the radius of circle 2000 , Its 100 thousands of loops that does algorithm checking  for each pixel. if you understand what i mean. You can check the code

Comment: Looping does not consume any memory, only time.

Comment: hey . I have other question . Can software like ms paint be made in a game engine? I mean does software use loops like that  of game loops ?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at SDL2_gfx library. 
[Here](https://github.com/keera-studios/SDL2_gfx/blob/5311c24935ba3d7647fa2199e8046cf29bf3351c/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.c#L1814) is draw circle implementation from it.
You may use this library to draw some primitives with SDL or just borrow some code from it.

Comment: I din't want to use library as I wanted to know how they implement drawing and filling  circles in a library  . Well I have out that bressenham's circle drawing algorithm is best way to draw circle and save some memory . I want to find out best way to fill circle now .